# How to resolve the error “Spawning child procees: invalid argument …” in flymake for erlang?

Tags: emacs, erlang, flymake

I'm trying to enable flymake for erlang on emacs for windows, and I'm encountering a problem.

when i type `M-x` `flymake-mode` `RET` while in a buffer of a file named e.erl I get an error mesesage saying:

> Flymake: Failed to launch syntax check process
>   'E:/emacs-24.3/.emacs.d/flymake/eflymake' with args (e_flymake.erl):
>   Spawning child process: invalid argument. Flymake will be switched
>   Off.

currently, I have my .emacs and .emacs.d directory in the path E:/emacs-24.3, and my flymake file is in the path described in the error message. i used this page [EmacsWiki: Flymake Erlang](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeErlang) to create the flymake file and to configure the .emacs file (added the lines as ordered, and changed the path of the flymake file according to the path it's in).

I tried to change the line `#!/usr/bin/env escript` at the start of the flymake file to the line  `#!C:/Program Files/erl5.10.2/bin escript` as this is the path where the escript file is in, but the problem has stayed the same.

I work on Windows 7 with emacs 24.3.